# Android App | Consent Form Does Not Show at All

Tags: android, kotlin, admob, ads, gdprconsentform

Recently I received this notification.

> Later this year, Google will require all publishers serving ads to EEA and UK users to use a Google-certified Consent Management Platform (CMP). You can use any Google-certified CMP for this purpose, including Google's own consent management solution. If you are interested in using Google's consent management solution, start by setting up your GDPR message and implementing the UMP SDK. Learn more

I followed the instructions on this page: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/privacy

but the form doesn't show.

I'm using the latest adMob SDK versoin.I create the message on the AdMob "Privacy & Messaging".

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

private lateinit var consentInformation: ConsentInformation
private lateinit var consentForm: ConsentForm

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


    val debugSettings = ConsentDebugSettings.Builder(this)
        .setForceTesting(true)
        .setDebugGeography(DebugGeography.DEBUG_GEOGRAPHY_EEA)
        .build()

    val params = ConsentRequestParameters
        .Builder()
        .setConsentDebugSettings(debugSettings)
        .build()

    consentInformation = UserMessagingPlatform.getConsentInformation(this)
    consentInformation.requestConsentInfoUpdate(
        this,
        params,
        {
            if (consentInformation.isConsentFormAvailable) {
                loadForm()
            }
        },

        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"${it.errorCode} && ${it.message}",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

    )

    setContent {
}

private fun loadForm() {

    // Loads a consent form. Must be called on the main thread.
    UserMessagingPlatform.loadConsentForm(
        this,
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"0000000000",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            if (consentInformation.consentStatus == ConsentInformation.ConsentStatus.REQUIRED) {
                Toast.makeText(this,"2222222",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                consentForm.show(
                    this
                ) {
                    if (consentInformation.consentStatus == ConsentInformation.ConsentStatus.OBTAINED) {
                        // App can start requesting ads.
                        Toast.makeText(
                            this,
                            "${it?.errorCode} && ${it?.message}",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                        ).show()
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this,
                        "${it?.errorCode} && ${it?.message}",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show()
                    // Handle dismissal by reloading form.
                    loadForm()
                }
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this,"333333",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        },
        {
            // Handle the error.
            Toast.makeText(this,"${it.errorCode} && ${it.message}",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    )
}}
```

**the code reach the toast that display "222" but the form does not appear !!**

Comment: Have you tried adding `addTestDeviceHashedId`? See this: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/privacy#testing

Comment: I'm using the emulator so there no need to add the hashID.

Comment: Can you tried on a real device?

Comment: I fixed the issue but I am not sure if I need to put the ad request inside the OnConsentFormLoadSuccessListener. because the ads loaded before I press consent?

Comment: As per the docs and guidelines, you can initialise the MobileAds SDK early on but request the ads after the user gives the input in the form.

Comment: Did you setup the form in the admob website?

Comment: Yes, Now I'm just wondering about the request and where to implement it.

Comment: the form is showing now.I am asking about the request

Comment: Here it says you need consent first before initializing SDK https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/Ty9rFC2TfwA so I'd put it when the user already gave a response (in `onConsentFormDismissed`), and where there's no need to ask (when it's not `REQUIRED`, so inside the `else` with the `333333` toast).

Comment: @MarwanTalal What was the actual issue in your case? I feel to be stuck on the same thing.